# "No Load Speed" for Series DC Motor - What does it mean?

Tags: motors

The [datasheet for the Maxon 110121](https://www.maxongroup.co.uk/medias/sys_master/root/8881643847710/EN-21-167.pdf) series-wound DC motor lists both "No Load Speed" and "No Load Current" as data points, and I do not understand what it is trying to communicate with these numbers.

- The characteristic graph shows (as should be expected) the speed rising asymptotically as load is reduced. It looks like it hits the maximum permissable speed (16,000rpm) at ~3mNm.
- The "No Load Speed" is slower than the max permissable speed (10,400rpm) which on the graph relates to ~4mNm.
- Given the bottom scales, however, the "No Load Current" (16.9mA) does appear to relate to a value at or near 0mNm

[image: Load/Speed characteristic for Maxon 110121]

Clearly these numbers are not referring to the same point on the curve, and it seems like the "No Load Current" can be understood by its plain meaning. So what does "No Load Speed" mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Load in this context means the resistance to turning. In other words when the motor is only turning its own shaft with nothing connected to it.

The max speed is about the shaft and bearings, which means that if the motor is driven externally (for example it's powering a cart that is rolling downhill) then you shouldn't let the shaft's speed get above 16k rpm because that would damage the bearings.

Comment: But it exceeds the "No Load Speed" and the maximum speed at ~3mNm; at which point it is, by definition, under load.

Comment: Max Permissible Speed is only about how fast you allow the shaft to rotate. This can happen while the motor is unpowered and/or driven externally. No Load Speed is about how fast the motor will spin itself which is independent from how fast the shaft can spin without damaging the bearings.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, Ratchet Freak. That is indeed the plain meaning of the words, and it is what I would expect when looking at other motors. My question stems from the fact that the numbers and the graph in the datasheet contradict this. At no load the speed must be significantly greater than 10,400rpm, so what does it mean when it says its "No load speed" is 10,400rpm?

Comment: it means that if you power the motor with it's input power and there is nothing connected to the shaft then the shaft will rotate at 10400 rpm

Comment: The graph in the data sheet shows that (because it is a series motor) with nothing connected to the shaft, it will rotate significantly faster than 10,400rpm.

Answer (score 1):

The no-load current is not zero  at the no-load speed because it takes power to stir up the air inside the motor housing and to spin the bearings against friction. The no-load current times the source voltage equals the *windage losses* for the motor, which it is dissipating with no *external load* on the motor as it is spinning at the no-load speed, plus any I^2R losses in the windings.

The written specifications that accompany the chart state without question that at the voltage specified for the motor (12 volts), it will spin at 10,400 RPM with no external load. If you apply *more* than the rated voltage of 12 volts, the motor will spin *faster* and enough extra voltage will indeed spin the motor at the bearing speed limit of 16,000 RPM.

But at the nameplate speed of 7700 RPM and with 12 volts on the terminals, the motor will be drawing 0.586 amps and hence will be dissipating a total of 7 watts, of which 5 is useful work and 2 is heat dissipated in the windings.

Comment: This is more helpful, thank you. As I said elsewhere, I do understand the basic princples of motors, and what "No Load Speed" and "No Load Current" mean in a general context. I think you're saying that I've misunderstood what the chart is communicating.

Because series motors should typically not be unloaded due to their runaway speed often exceeding the bearing limit, and the chart showed a runaway speed with decreased load I assumed the line was the speed/torque characteristic. You say instead it is actually the region where 5W useful work is exerted?